# Adding another login creates a new account

Tags: support, bug, login, email

I'm gradually moving to a new email address, so I tried to add it as a new login using the "add more logins..." button:

[image: profile settings]

That took me to this form:

[image: add login form]

I filled in the new email.

But when I try login in with that email, it takes me to a new profile. (with the same name as my current one). This is not the behaviour I expected. I expected "another login option" not "create a new profile". This is problematic since I would like to be able to log in with my new email, and also since the new profile doesn't come with moderator privileges.

Comment: To fix the immediate problem, be sure to have your account merged so it doesn't seem like you created a sock puppet. This will probably add the other login method as well.

Comment: Reported for merging. I will check if this adds the other login method when they get merged.

Comment: I don't think the same account can have two email/password logins. This is meant for one account having both email/password and Google logins, for example. Not sure, better wait for official response.

Comment: That may be so. The options in the second image still gives the impression that I can do such a thing, and in neither case do I expect to create another profile.